# Load html content from ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, json, opencart2.x

I am creating an application in opencart in which the controller returns output in json form. If i do `$('.my-div').html(json['output'])` then its working fine. But how can i filter particular `div` or `table` from that response and put only that filtered html in my div. I know about `$('.my-div').load('index.php?route=mymodule/subpage' .my-div > * );` But it doesn't work as my controller is created to return output not to generate.

What my controller returns is

`$json['output'] = $this->load->view('default/template/mymodule/mytemplate.tpl', $data);`

**Edit**

What i am getting in response is 
`json['output'] = '<div>......</div><table class="myclass"></table>';`

I want to load only `myclass` in my div. So how can i filter only `myclass table` from response.? I've tried filter but its giving me error.

Comment: do you want to load part of  html code from a entire code?

Comment: @syedmohamed yes! I've edited my question for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Like *Raghubendra* said, it's better to only keep the `html` you need in the `.tpl` file, but if you can't do that for whatever reason, you can try to filter it on the server side using **xPath** [it's not the fastest way, but it's a clean way to get the result]. Here is how I think you can do it:

```
$output = $this->load->view('default/template/mymodule/mytemplate.tpl', $data);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($output); // @ is to suppress all warnings related to the fact that html is not a proper dom document
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$match = $xpath->query('//table[@class="myclass"]');

/* $match is not an array, it implements 'Traversable', you can't access your <table> node using $match[0],
 you need a foreach that will only loop once if you have one <table class="myclass"> element */
foreach($match as $table) {
    $json['output'] = $table->ownerDocument->saveHTML($table); // saveHTML allows you to get the output in an HTML string
}
```

**N.B:** Please note that you need to change this code in case you have multiple `<table class="myclass">`, I would recommend using `iterator_to_array($match);` to transform the node list to an array so you can access it using `$match[0]...` and avoid the `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only a part of the html in your div then why are you rendering the whole tpl file. Why don't you remove the html code that you don't want to use.

Suppose if your mytemplate.tpl has

```
<div>
---------
--------
</div>

<table class="myclass"></table>

<div>
---------
--------
</div>
```

Then why don't you only keep the table code are remove all the other code as you are not using it while rendering the tpl file.

Comment: I am using it in other file too. That's why :(

Comment: In that case you have to pass only the required html in the json..

You can use file_get_contents to get all the contents of the tpl file in the php controller and then alter the html accordingly.

Don't get all the html to jQuery as it is not easy to handle it in jQuery.

Comment: Can i filter it from json?

Comment: Yes filter it in the php controller only.